# avoid tail recursion python for DP

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, tail-recursion

I have written in Python the following recursive function for computing a solution within a DP algorithm for a weighted interval scheduling problem where the intervals are "sorted_operations". I am following the "Algorithm Design" book by Kleinberg and Tardos, and OPT and p_list have been already calculated. It seems to work for relatively small instances, but as soon as my size of the problem increases I exceed the "maximum recursion depth" and I get an error. Since increasing the sys.setrecursionlimit crashes my kernel, I am wondering if there are other ways to write this function.

```
solution_set = []
def compute_solution(j):
    if j<=0:
       pass
    else:
        if sorted_operations[j]['weight'] + OPT[p_list[j]] > OPT[j - 1]:
            solution_set.append(sorted_operations[j])
            print(j)
            compute_solution(p_list[j])
        else:
            compute_solution(j - 1)

compute_solution(len(sorted_operations) - 1)
```

Comment: the code is a bit confusing, but you can use iterations instead of recursion.

Comment: Without seeing `p_list`, `sorted_operations` (or at least a subset of it) and `OPT` I can't really offer a recommendation or solution. Also, what do you mean when you say the "size of your problem increases"? What is it increasing from and what to? If `len(sorted_operations)` ~ 1,000 then I'd say you have a problem but if `len(sorted_operations)` ~ 1,000,000 maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your code, I can't really offer a detailed solution. However, one part of your algorithm did stick out in my mind: `compute_solution(j - 1)`. Since `j` is an integer, calling the algorithm again with `j - 1` fits a loop better than a method call, especially since these tend to be somewhat expensive in Python. So, I would modify your algorithm like this:

```
solution_set = []
def compute_solution(j):
    while (j > 0):
        if sorted_operations[j]['weight'] + OPT[p_list[j]] > OPT[j - 1]:
            solution_set.append(sorted_operations[j])
            print(j)
            compute_solution(p_list[j])
            return
        else:
            j = j - 1

compute_solution(len(sorted_operations) - 1)
```

Depending on how often that `else` statement is run, this could be a major benefit.

Comment: Thank you @Woody. I gave it a try and it seems to work for larger instances (e.g. 10,000 intervals). However, it is not very clear why the usage of the <break> in the if statement.

Comment: @Michele If you don't use the `break` then you'll get stuck in an infinite-loop as the value of `j` is only updated in the `else` and it's unclear whether or not the `if` would evaluate to the same result on subsequent calls. Note that a `return` statement would work equally well if you want to use that as your base case but I was unsure as to whether or not other code existed after the code you had in your question